# Re-apply the PhD program that I previously got offer and turned down

Tags: phd, graduate-school, application

My situation is as follows:

1. I applied to PhD program A and B, and got offers from both.
2. However, the offer of A came too late which was after the deadline of decision for B. So I took offer B, and got the offer A one day after accepting B.
3. At that time I struggled a bit, and decided not to turned down B because I thought there were an ethical issue.
4. Now I am about to start the second year PhD at B, but I don't feel like this is the appropriate university to continue my study. So I am thinking about re-applying A and drop B.

My question is that in my case, is it possible to simply do a transfer from B to A and continue my PhD, instead of dropping B and re-applying A, or is there another way which is simpler than re-applying?

Also, do graduate programs allow one to apply PhD programs while studying one? These questions all depends, I guess, but I wonder if there are general cases.

Answer (score 3):

To transfer means that you will need to find a new supervisor who is prepared to take you and your project on in the current state.

That might be a challenge and a bigger challenge than you realise, it is not just walk out the front door of B and in through the front door of A...

Comment: Generally, if, in an ideal case, there is a professor in C (not necessarily in univ. A) who is willing to take me, and my supervisor also agrees, do I still have to go over the normal application process of C? This should depend on univ. C though...

Comment: Have you got an "ideal" case? All cases like this are individual... A friend spent two years sorting a supervisor for his partially completed PhD thesis which he subsequently completed successfully.

Comment: It is not the ideal case at all at the moment. I only have an invitation letter from C for a research attachment, which is far from PhD taken over. I guess what I am looking for is a way to get myself out of B, without going through another application, which include English test (as mine has expired already), reference letters, etc.